# One async call instead of two GWT

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling

I have a text area and a button. When I put some text in the text area (on paste browse event, all other events are ignored) or click a button the same call is sent to the server via value change handler for the text area and click handler for the button. If data is wrong, server throws an exception and it returns to a client as message box.

So when I put some data to text area and click a button, two message boxes appear. Is there any way to make one message box appear for such case?

Some code as example of the issue:

```
textArea.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        fireHandlers();
    }
});

button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        fireHandlers();
    }
});

//............

private void fireHandlers() {
    for (MyProcessHandler handler : myHandlersList) {
    handler.handle();
    }
}

//............

public static interface MyProcessHandler {
    public void handle();
}

//............

addMyProcessHandler(new MyProcessHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle() {
        AsyncCallback<String[]> ac = new AsyncCallbackAdapter<String[]>() {
            public void onSuccess(String[] data) {
                //post processing
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(throwable);
            }
        };
        RemoteCall.getMyService().getResultFromData(textArea.getData(), ac);
    }
});
```

Comment: just introduce a flag to ensure the single call, if fireHandlers executed switch flag and all the other calls will be ignored. On response just switch flag back. I also did a duplicate request filter for one of the projects, but it's not required for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what Alexey says is something like this:

```
private boolean eventFired = false;

textArea.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        fireHandlers();
    }
});

button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        fireHandlers();
    }
});

//............

private void fireHandlers() {
    if(!eventFired) {
        eventFired = true;
        for (MyProcessHandler handler : myHandlersList) {
            handler.handle();
        }
    }
}

//............

public static interface MyProcessHandler {
    public void handle();
}

//............

addMyProcessHandler(new MyProcessHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle() {
        AsyncCallback<String[]> ac = new AsyncCallbackAdapter<String[]>() {
            public void onSuccess(String[] data) {
                eventFired = false;
                //post processing
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(throwable);
                eventFired = false;
            }
        };
        RemoteCall.getMyService().getResultFromData(textArea.getData(), ac);
    }
});
```

Make your decision where to put `eventFired=false` in your code. Maybe after processing the answer from the server, maybe just after starting the async call to enable another actions while waiting for the server.

Comment: I tried such variant, but flag is set to false before message box appears and I manage to click button. As a result two message boxes appear :( I thought of idea to suppress events and if message box appears I'll cancel event suppression or something like this. But this is only idea without solution, at least I don't see it now.

Comment: If the problem is just that flag is set false before message box appear then you can move it to the right place - to the last line of the code of the `onFailure()` method of the super class.
Maybe the difference will be the call `MyClass.setEventFired(false)` instead of `eventFired = false`. `eventFired` member and `setEventFired(boolean eventFired)` should be static then.
Maybe super should contain member `eventFired`.

Comment: I tried different variants. When there's async call in another class -  events are blocked correctly till result is ready. But if async call is in the same class, then button click is put to the queue and after first call returns error and shows MessageBox, flag is set to false and next call is made. So I have two message boxes at the end :(

Comment: I have an idea. Probably you can get rid of this problem if you handle **server's** responses another ways. Maybe if text changes, then you could just change (or insert) a label with error message; when button is clicked, then message box remains. If both of them happens, user will see the message box and when it disappears, no other message box appears, just a label reminds him to the problem.